# curl error : Protocol " http" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: php, curl

This is my code and the error is showing as curl error : Protocol " http" not supported or disabled in libcurl

```
<?php
//Please Enter Your Details

$user="mysite"; //your username 
$password="12345"; //your password
$mobilenumbers="1234567890"; //enter Mobile numbers comma seperated 
$message = "Your unique id is 5544"; //enter Your Message
$senderid="WEBSMS"; //Your senderid

$url=" http://sapteleservicess.in/SMS_API/sendsms.php"; $message = urlencode($message);

$ch = curl_init();

if (!$ch){die("Couldn't initialize a cURL handle");} 
echo "vannu1";
$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
echo "vannu2";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
echo "vannu3";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
echo "vannu4";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
echo "vannu5";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=$user&password=$password&mobile=$mobilenumbers& message=$message&sendername=$senderid&routetype=1");
echo "vannu6";
$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
echo "vannu7";
//If you are behind proxy then please uncomment below line and provide your proxy ip with port. // $ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "PROXY IP ADDRESS:PORT");

$curlresponse = curl_exec($ch); // execute 
//if(curl_errno($ch))

echo 'curl error : '. curl_error($ch);
 if (empty($ret)) {
echo "vannu8";
// some kind of an error happened 
die(curl_error($ch));
echo "vannu9";
curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler 
} else {
   echo "vannu10"; 
$info = curl_getinfo($ch); curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler
echo "vannu11";
echo $curlresponse; //echo "Message Sent Succesfully" ;

}
?>
```

Comment: `(whitespace)http` is not a supported protocol indeed. did you mean the [`HTTP` protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) ? curl supports that one. just remove the whitespace from the start of the uri.

Comment: You also have an extra whitespace in your POST fields. `& message=`

Comment: and you don't urlencode $user / $password / $mobilenumbers / $message / $senderid, check [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)  (or better yet, [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php))

Answer (score 2):

This occurs when you have some whitespace (such as return or newline) before the URL. So curl gets confused.  It can also occur if you misstype `http` or `https`.